# [CCDirector sharedDirector].secondsPerFrame returns value of zero

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I’m looking for a way to fetch FPS rate, and I found property secondsPerFrame in CCDirector, however every CCLog says that `[CCDirector sharedDirector].secondsPerFrame` is “0.000000″

If I could tailor code to immediately adjust to drops in frame rate, the game would basically never run below 60fps, which would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I could tailor code to immediately adjust to drops in frame rate,
>   the game would basically never run below 60fps, which would be
>   amazing.

If it were possible we'd find this as a standard feature in render engines. Alas, it is not.

To detect a dropped frame implies that a frame has had to be dropped already. The overhead of switching code paths, especially back to the "high detail" version is often too prohibitive as well.

Besides the headaches of designing a game whose visuals or even algorithms may vary at any time.

Plus player perception will be rather negative - consider streaming videos that automatically adjust to bandwidth and sometimes appear very blocky for a few seconds.

It is often better to limit the game to 30 fps if you can't match 60 fps all the time, and design it against a steady 30 fps rather than a fluctuating 40 to 60 fps.

Anyhow, if you log `secondsPerFrame` and get 0.0000 maybe you logged using the wrong format specifier. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"spf: %f", [CCDirector sharedDirector].secondsPerFrame);
```

Keep in mind that this value may be an average over multiple frames and it may not be updated in release builds. Check the code for any #if/#ifdef.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean, but I think in this specific case, the user won't notice it because I remove the hard-to-see particles, and it basically only took 5-10 lines of code to add. I asked this problem elsewhere, and the problem is that secondsPerFrame is not calculated in calculateMPF unless ShowStats Label is enabled...

Comment: You can try and replicate the code that calculates the spf in a custom class. If I remember correctly it's just a few lines of code storing the last timestamp and comparing it with the most recent one, plus maybe an #import for the standard time functions.